# Re-indexing dates with pandas UDF results in "java.lang.NullPointerException"

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark dataframe with a set of categorical columns defining groups, a date column, and several columns with numerical values. The dates for certain groups do not span the entire range, from date.min() to date.max(), and I am trying to "re-index" the dataframe to fill the gaps. I can do that in pandas but the following grouped_map is not working:

```
schema_df = input_df.schema

@pandas_udf(schema_df, PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)
def my_udf(df):
  df = df.sort_values(by='date')
  
  df = df.set_index('date')
  df = df.asfreq('D')
  df = df.reset_index(level='date')

  return df

output_df = input_df.groupby('cat_col_A', 'cat_col_B').apply(my_udf)
```

As mentioned in the title the resulting spark fails with a "java.lang.NullPointerException" error - the original dataframe has no missing values and anyway the schema has nullable columns. Furthermore, executing the normal function on a sample of the pandas dataframe (obtained with toPandas()) returns the expected result. Any ideas on what might be causing this issue?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: What's the data type of the `date` column in the Spark dataframe schema?

Comment: It's a DateType column

Comment: mind showing a sample dataframe?

Comment: which values do you want to fill the gaps with? I've often created a df from min-date to max-date and used a left join for filling the gaps